# How to print an element from the corresponding immediate next column after searching the element in the current column?

Tags: linux, shell-script, grep

I have thousands of lines as seen in the following list.
file name = "textfile"

```
3 2 3 1 4 7
5 8 6 8 9 8
8 9 4 7 3 9 
2 3 4 4 9 2 
2 2 0 9 4 0 
0 9 8 2 4 0
```

I have to search a particular element – say, in the fifth column – using a condition.
(Actually I have to find the maximum.)
I want this output.
 maximum of fifth column = 9

line : 
        5 8 6 8 9 8

```
    2 3 4 4 9 2
```

I used the following code.

```
var=$(cat newfifth1 | awk 'BEGIN {max = 0} {if ($5>max) max = $5} END {print max}')
cat textfile | grep "$var" | cat $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 >> newtextfile
```

## but this does not work!!!

If possible please give me a simpler method and a method using arrays.

Comment: How is "maximum" defined?

Comment: All the elements are numbers. Just numbers. Sorry that I have put it in alphabets. Please consider all the elements as numbers. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Please edit your question to fix that: it is a critical detail and needs to be clarified.

Comment: @nick ad, your code is broken; so it makes no sense to ask for a simpler code than what you did. Instead, try to explain precisely what you want to do, specifically with the second line of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your data samples in your question this seems to be what you want (otherwise clarify your question, please):

```
awk '$5 > max { max = $5 ; out = $0 } END { print out }' datafile
```

This will print that line in datafile where the value in the 5th column is the maximum.

The program works as follows: For each line the fifth column element will be compared against the stored maximum `max` (which is initially 0), and if a larger value is found `max` gets that value assigned (for subsequent comparisons) and the current line (`$0`) containing the maximum is stored in variable `out`. As the final action of the program the value of variable `out` will be printed.

In case you have only values less than zero in your data you will need (because of the implicit initialization of `max` with zero) some extension; often it is enough to initialize the variable `max` explicitly with a value known to be lower than the values in your data, e.g. using `BEGIN { max = -999999 }`, but you can also use a generic code pattern as follows:

```
awk '(max==0 && max=="") || $5 > max { max = $5 ; out = $0 } END { print out }' datafile
```

Read the `(max==0 && max=="")` part of the condition as: "Is `max` still undefined?" (i.e. not yet a value assigned).

Comment: Thanks a ton !!! your code works perfect! works like magic!! But I know how it works. I dont get what $0 is. Would you please explain the code? You saved my day!

Comment: Good, but not perfect.  This will fail (not produce any output) if every value in the fifth column is ≤ 0.  And otherwise (if there are positive value(s)) it prints only the first line that contains the maximum value,

Comment: @nick ad; I'll edit my answer to add an explanation.

Comment: Thank you! As G-man said, when I tried changing this to < 0, it does not print anything. I am new to shell script. Would you please tell me from where shall i begin? I am told to handle data using shell script and I had learnt basic C programming about 5 years ago. Thank you in advance for the answer.

Comment: @nick ad; have you tried the `(max==0 && max=="")` extension that I added to my answer below my explanations?

Comment: @Janis,@G man, thank you both for your explanation. This really helped. I also wanted to know the use of counters in arrays. Wish you guys many good days ahead!

Comment: @Janis, Isnt it $5 < max in your extension...?

Comment: @nick ad; no, you still want a maximum, don't you? That means that any new value `$5` that has to be compared against the stored maximum `max` must exceed it to replace the old maximum. (You would use `<` in case you are seeking the minimum.)

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of solutions.

#### Two-pass (without array):

```
awk '
    {
        if (NR == FNR) {
                if ($5 > max) max = $5
        } else {
                if ($5 == max) print
        }
    }' textfile textfile
```

- `NR` is the record number (line number) counted across all the input. 
  `FNR` is the line number *within the current file*. 
  So, for example, if you run `awk` with input from two files:
  `fileC`, which is three lines long, and `fileD`, which is four lines long,
  `NR` and `FNR` will take on the following values:

  ```
  NR    FNR
   1     1
   2     2
   3     3
   4     1
   5     2
   6     3
   7     4
  ```

  So testing `NR == FNR` is a classic trick for seeing
  whether you’re looking at the first file.
- So, the above reads the input file twice
  (did you notice the last line, where `textfile` was specified twice?). 
  On the first pass, if finds the maximum value;
  on the second pass, it prints all the lines that contain that value.

#### One-pass (using an array):

```
awk '
    {
        if ($5 >= max) {
                if ($5 > max) {
                        max = $5
                        delete result
                        count = 0
                }
                result[++count] = $0
        }
    }
END { for (i = 0; i <= count; i++) print result[i] }' textfile
```

- This stores lines that match the maximum value in an array
  called `result`.  This is tricky,
  because we don’t know the maximum value until we get all the way
  through the file (since we’re reading the file only once). 
  So, whenever we encounter a value that’s higher
  than any we’ve seen before (i.e., we find a new maximum),
  we clean out (`delete`) the `result` array and start over.
- Then, when we get to the end of the file, we print what we’ve found.

---

Note: The above commands fail if every value in the fifth column is ≤ 0. 
To handle that case, change `if ($5 >…`
to `if (max == ""  ||  $5 >…` throughout
(including the `if ($5 >= max)` test).

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and explanation. I appreciate it!
Would pls you tell me these two things:
1. in the second pass, you are comparing the max with $5 and printing the line. correct me if I am wrong. 
2.Would you please tell me when to use two textfiles for the awk statement .

Comment: @nick ad; (ad 1) Yes that is correct; since the maximum value is known at that point, it's printed if it matches. (ad 2.) The two files are given to emulate a two-pass processing on the same file.